# Include exe used in child process

Tags: electron, child-process

I am spawning a child process with the path defined as

```
private readonly executablePath = path.join(__static, '/game/ArcMages.exe');
```

(This is in vue electron). 
I put the exe under public/.
Once the program is built and installed, it seems to lose track of the .exe. Do I need to put this folder somewhere else/change my build config?

Comment: I never used vue but with `electron-builder` you need to put the binary outside of the asar after installation because it can't be executed if it is in the asar. Maybe you have a similar problem. Can you add the error message you are getting to your question?

Comment: It is simple, it can't find the file specified. I would think electron has a specific directory that gets included in the install that does not get compiled in any way.

Comment: Does it search for the file inside the asar? The path where it searches for the file is relevant here.

Comment: Currently my dirty fix is to put it in a folder I include with "extraFolders". It searched on that path.

But there has to be a folder that is designed to have content that gets put at the root level after install?

Comment: do you build an nsis installer? What do you use to build your electron distribution? The [Vue CLI Plugin Electron Builder](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/)?

Comment: Yes, I use yarn electron:build as defined by the vue cli plugin electron builder. It creates a bundled installer, but it also creates a folder with all of the files unpacked.

Comment: ah ok, I begin to understand, you build on windows? If not, for what platform do you build?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190650/discussion-between-jeff-b-and-rhayene).